# .NET 4.5 framework is installed and enabled,but not recognized by sharepoint installation guide

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I have .net 4.5 framework installed on windows server 2012 r2. I want to verify it under registry ,but it is not showing up in the registry. ( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP) . The NDP subregistry has only client folder but not the 'FULL' showing the 4.5 version. Am trying to install sharepoint 2013 sp1, which errors on saying " This product requires Microsoft .NET frame 4.5".

I see that .net 4.5 is installed,but is not recognized by the sharepoint installation setup. How do i verify this.

[screenshot of registry,sharepoint installation setup and server feature saying that .NET 4.5 is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9wx6.png)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61239/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5)?

Comment: thanks much for the pointer.. that helped and am able to progress!